# How do I set my VSCode's initial interface?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open my VSCode in startup menu, the Code show me an interface of a file called untitled. How can I set the Code to show me the interface of shortcuts like the picture when I open it instead of an untitled file? [image: image description here]

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting to get exactly the page you want but you can view the `welcome` page instead of untitled file.
You can change this in `setting`.
Here are the steps to do that:

1. Open `Prefrences` > `Setting`.
2. Search for `welcome`
3. and edit this value to true as `"workbench.welcome.enabled": true`

Comment: So what caused the problem? The plugins? Or my computer is going wrong?

Comment: That is not the problem. It's the default behavior.

Comment: Is it the only way to set the Code to the  Welcome page? But I just want to get the page of shortcuts.

Comment: Yes that's the way